# Subclasses in SQLAlchemy

Tags: python, sqlite, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

I'm making a catalog using sqlalchemy, the catalog consists of categories, and items. I'm trying to make subcategories that have a parent category without making a subcategory class, but I'm unsure of how to do this. My goal is to have a Category class that has the functionality of this but works:

```
class Category(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'category'

    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = Column(String(250), nullable=False)
    parent_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('parent.id'), nullable=True)
    parent = relationship(Category)
```

Obviously this doesn't work because Category has not been defined when you're defining it. What is the way to successfully do this?

Comment: http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/self_referential.html "Adjacency List Relationships" suggests quoting the class name - `relationship("Category")`

Comment: This works but when setting the parent such as: Parent: `category1 = Category(name="Entertainment")` Child: `category2 = Category(name="Video Games", parent=[category1])` the result in the table is setting Entertainment's parent_id to Video Games instead of vice versa?

Comment: I'm not following that. Does your quoted code have a `def __init__(...` line missing from it? Are `name` and `parent` parameters?

Comment: Sorry, I'm using the model shown in the question, just updated with relationship("Category") instead. Name and parent are columns in the Category table

Comment: Follow the already linked documentation and add the `remote_side=[id]` argument to relationship, creating a many to one relationship.

Comment: @JoeP Declarative provides a default `__init__` that maps keyword arguments to attributes, if one is not defined in the mapped class.